# ¿Como imprimir decimales c sharp?

Tags: c#

estoy empezando con la programación en C# y tengo un problema al imprimir el resultado de una suma la cual tiene decimales, al momento de imprimir lo hace como entero y como decimal  este es el código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int limite;
        double numero;
        double suma = 0.0;
        int contador = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero maximo de numeros a sumar");
        limite = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while(contador < limite)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero");
            numero = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            suma = suma + numero;
            contador++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("La suma total es de: " + suma);
    }
```

Por ejemplo si ingreso los números **2.5** y **1.6** me imprime
41 en lugar de 4.1

Comment: Tu código es correcto, imprime bien el resultado. Puedes confirmar acá: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RrgpYs

Comment: `La suma total es de: 4.1` tu mismo programa escribe bien el `4.1`...

Comment: No se si es problema de mvisual studio o de mi consola pero a mi me imprime como un numero entero

Comment: Tu problema seguramente esta en la Cultura de la app, ya que seguramente si pruebas usando la , (Coma) el resultado te dara correcto y si usas el . (punto) no, o al reves por eso es la cultura la que te juega a favor o en contra segun los calculos que quieras hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema seguramente radica en que usas el . (punto) para trabajar con decimal y la `Culture` de tu App no la toma pero si te toma la ,(coma) Puedes cambiar la cultura en el codigo y trabajar bien con el .(punto) como decimal.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int limite = 0;
        double numero = 0.0;
        double suma = 0.0;
        int contador = 0;

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero maximo de numeros a sumar");

        limite = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        while (contador < limite)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero");

            numero = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());

            suma = suma + numero;

            contador++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("La suma total es de: " + suma);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar el método `ToString()`. Quedaría tipo:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Suma total: " + suma.ToString("0.##"));
```

Comment: ¿Como se usa `ToString`? ¿Qué esa cosa que le pasas como parámetro? ¿Que otras cosas se pueden hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Solo usa el `ToString()` .. sería algo así

```
Console.WriteLine("La suma total es de: " + suma.ToString("0.##"));
```